# AWS: Is it possible to retrieve the content of key that stored in KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

If the answer is no, how to deal with the data encryption when migrating your data from aws cloud to another cloud someday?

e.g. S3 object that has been encrypted by SSE-S3

Answer (score 5):

Its **not possible**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#key_management):

> By default, AWS KMS creates the key material for a CMK. You **cannot extract, export, view, or manage** this key material.

The **exception is** when you [import your own keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html) into KMS. Since you import the key material, you can use the same one in the other provider if it supports importing keys.

When you copy your objects to other storage provider, AWS will **transparently decrypt** them. The new provider will have to encrypt your data using their own keys.

So basically, the migration involves, decryption of your data, transfer of the data to a new provider, and encryption using a new key.

The only way to transport encrypted data from s3 is if you use SSE-C in S3, which stands for [customer-provided encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html). In this case you are fully responsible for encryption and decryption of your files. AWS and the new provider only store the encrypted files:

> Using server-side encryption with customer-provided encryption keys (SSE-C) allows you to **set your own encryption keys**.

Comment: SSE-C stands for Server-Side Encryption with Customer-provided keys... Encryption and decryption happen on AWS infrastructure with the key that the client provides, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, data is not encrypted using the keys stored in a Key Management Service (KMS).

Instead, when a file needs to be encrypted:

- A random encryption key is generated that is **specific to that file only**
- The file is encrypted using that key
- The key is then encrypted using the keys stored in the KMS and the encrypted key is stored with the encrypted data

Later, when the file needs to be decrypted:

- The encrypted key is decrypted using the KMS
- The file is decrypted using the decrypted key

Thus, if you wish to move encrypted data to a different system, you merely need to decrypt the file-specific encryption keys using the KMS and re-encrypt them using the new KMS. The encrypted files can then be copied to the new system without needing to be decrypted.

Here's a picture from [Server-side encryption with KMS managed keys (SSE-KMS) - AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate Guide [Book]](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/aws-certified-solutions/9781789130669/f4321cdd-edf6-45c6-a5ad-2fe59d17d280.xhtml):

[image: S3 Encryption]